# ClassNotFoundException in IDEA with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-annotations

I'm trying to add AndroidAnnotations to my maven/idea project. Here is what I have now:

#### Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ua.avtopoisk"
      android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.5">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:name=".AvtopoiskApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon"      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".activites.SearchActivity_"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activites.SearchResultActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>
```

#### maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <classifier>api</classifier>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

#### start activity

```
@EActivity(R.layout.search)
    public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    }
```

I also edited my project settings as shown here https://github.com/ealden/android-annotations-idea-test/blob/master/project-settings-guide.png

It compiles fine, but when i try to run this application i recive this:

```
10-16 16:39:49.789: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity    ComponentInfo{ua.avtopoisk/ua.avtopoisk.activites.SearchActivity_}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ua.avtopoisk.activites.SearchActivity_ in loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ua.avtopoisk-2.apk]
            at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
            at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   ua.avtopoisk.activites.SearchActivity_ in loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ua.avtopoisk-2.apk]
            at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
            at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
            ... 11 more
```

If you can give me any hint I would be thankful.

#### UPDATE

I've found that when i build my application by maven everything is ok, but when i buld it by IDEA i still have ClassNotFoundException.
I still have no idea what is wrong

#### UPDATE 2

I've tryed to build my project with eclipse and I've got same error. 
I also tried to build android annotations sample project (HelloWorldEclipse), I also have same error

Comment: interesting... even though u defined the activity in the manifest the class loader can't find it, if u remove the annotation everything works fine ? what's the annotation's job ? could it be that maven runs a extra task/compilation/modification to the apk to cause the annotation do their work or it should work in run time ? Also fi  you use full activity class name and not relative one is there a difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem! Folder gen with generated sources was excluded by IDEA (Settings->Compiler->Excludes). Now works fine, but I'm still intrested is it true way.

Comment: gen has only the R classes. if it contains anything else (like in Appcelerator) that's bad, I.E not standard.

Comment: And where should be located classes generated by android annotations?

Comment: In the end I changed my generated source directory name for annotation proccessor from "gen" to "target/generated-sources/r". So classes generated by android annotations now located there.